# Construct Xpath

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following repeated piece of the web-page:

```
<div class="txt ext">
 <strong class="param">param_value1</strong>            
 <strong class="param">param_value2</strong>                                                
</div>
```

I would like to extract separately values `param_value1` and `param_value2` using Xpath. How can I do it?

I have tried the following constructions:

```
'//strong[@class="param"]/text()[0]'
'//strong[@class="txt ext"]/strong[@class="param"][0]/text()'
'//strong[@class="param"]'
```

none of which returned me separately `param_value1` and `param_value2`.

P.S. I am using Python 2.7 and the latest version of Scrapy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my testing code:

```
test_content = '<div class="txt ext"><strong class="param">param_value1</strong><strong class="param">param_value2</strong></div>'

sel = HtmlXPathSelector(text=test_content)
sel.select('//div/strong[@class="param"]/text()').extract()[0]   
sel.select('//div/strong[@class="param"]/text()').extract()[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`//` means descendant or self. You are selecting any `strong` element in any context. `[...]` is a predicate which restricts your selection according to some boolean test. There is no `strong` element with a `class` attribute which equals `txt ext`, so you can exclude your second expression.

Your last expression will actually return a node-set of all the `strong` elements which have a `param` attribute. You can then extract individual nodes from the node set (use `[1]`, `[2]`) and then get their text contents (use `text()`).

Your first expression selects the text contents of both nodes but it's also wrong. It's in the wrong place and you can't select node zero (it doesn't exist). If you want the text contents of the first node you should use:

```
//strong[@class="param"][1]/text()
```

and you can use

```
//strong[@class="param"][2]/text()
```

for the second text.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your solution returns only the first top element, but not the whole list.

Comment: Your last expression returns the whole list, as a *nodeset* (not as text). You can then use Python to loop through each node and extract the text. If you want to use *one* XPath expression and return *all* the text, you will have to concatenate it.

Comment: Ex: `concat(//strong[@class="param"][1]/text(), ';', //strong[@class="param"][2]/text())` will return both strings separated by a semicolon.